# Implementing ProGuard in android

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I supossedly active proguard in my eclipse android app, uncommenting this

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
target=android-22
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
```

And exported Selecting the project>export, but i don't see any difference of size and i descompiled and is not replacing name of clases and that stuff.

Why is that? I am doing wrong?

I even try adding the code example of [A complete Android application](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) in proguard-project.txt

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /usr/local/java/android-sdk/platforms/android-9/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Comment: You are implementing nothing here. You are just using this tool

Comment: ok i dont speak english, so how do i integrate ProGuard?, i am new in this :(

Comment: You should also post your ProGuard config.

Comment: my proguard config is the example of the link  A complete Android application in the question